# implement virtual audio cable programmatically

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, multimedia, wdm

Virtual Audio Cable is a Windows WDM multimedia driver that allows a user to transfer audio streams from one application to another. I want to implement this functionality programmaticaly. I will prefer to do it in c#. Any developer can guide me how to do it

Comment: Using a driver **is** doing that programmatically.  What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually I want to implement capturing audio from sound card using c# myself (without installing Virtual Audio Cable)

Comment: You can't, unless the sound card's driver already supports capturing from its output.  There is a reason those drivers exist.

Comment: After Searching on internet I have found a way to start. Here's a good example how we can capture audio from sound card programmatically http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx

Comment: WASAPI is only available for Vista or later.  If you are only concerned about Vista and later, please put that in your question.

Comment: I started with the aim to capture sound from both XP and Win7. Then found that there's no option for XP. Now I am trying to do this only for Win7. WASAPI is good discovery for that